# How does Windows 7 Aero taskbar determine button hover-state background colour

Tags: buttons, icons, color, windows-os, hover

This has intrigued me for quite some time.

Does anyone know the algorithm Windows 7 Aero uses to determine the colour to use as the mouse-tracking hover highlight on taskbar buttons for currently-running apps?

[image: Windows 7 taskbar hover colours]

It is definitely based on the icon of the app, but I can't see a specific pattern of where it's getting the colour value from.

It **doesn't** seem to be any of the following:

- An average colour value from the entire icon, otherwise you would get brown all the time.
- The colour used the most in the image, otherwise you'd get yellow for the SQL Server Management Studio icon (6th from left). Also, the Chrome icon used red, green and yellow in equal measure.
- A colour located at certain pixel coordinates within the icon, because Chrome is red -indicating the top of the icon - and Notepad++ (2nd from right) is green - indicating the bottom of the icon.

Comment: Your question is possibly better suited for **[SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)**

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13637892/472021

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it’s not

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, the question was moved to [http://superuser.com/questions/730804/how-does-windows-7-calculate-the-color-to-use-for-taskbar-color-hot-tracking](http://superuser.com/questions/730804/how-does-windows-7-calculate-the-color-to-use-for-taskbar-color-hot-tracking)

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're looking for is called (by Microsoft) the "[Color hot-track](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/)".

As described [by Raymond Chen in this MSDN blog article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111206-00/?p=8963):

> Some people ask how it's done. It's really nothing special. The code
> just looks for the predominant color in the icon. (And, since visual
> designers are sticklers for this sort of thing, black, white, and
> shades of gray are not considered "colors" for the purpose of this
> calculation.)

Google uses a similar feature in its Most Visited/new tab page, which has been [thoroughly explained with code samples on this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Google-Chrome/How-does-Chrome-pick-the-color-for-the-stripes-on-the-Most-visited-page-thumbnails-Its-clearly-based-on-the-favicon-but-I-cant-tell-exactly-how-its-derived).

Comment: Well, there you go then! I was convinced it wasn't that, but I must have been wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, sorry I accepted your answer when I shouldn't have. The article you link to doesn't really explain what "predominant color" means, or how it is calculated. There are many comments on that blog asking my question with no clear cut answer given. Thanks for the info though - I didn't know it was called "color hot-tracking".